# Combine two arrays In one without duplicates

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

What is the best aproach using ES6+ sintaxe to go from this:

```
const mapedTopicsArray = [
                            ['javascript', 'reactjs'],
                            ['Java', 'reactjs'],                   
                         ]
```

To this:

```
const topicsArrayMergedWithoutDuplicates = ['javascript', 'reactjs','Java']
```

I know that if I use .reduce() I can acomplish that, but I can't figure out how, the nested Array thing is bogging me.

Comment: Look into `array.flat()`, `Set()` (the constructor specifically), and `Array.from()`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can easily achieve the result using [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and [`flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat).

```js
const mapedTopicsArray = [
  ["javascript", "reactjs"],
  ["Java", "reactjs"],
];

const topicsArrayMergedWithoutDuplicates  = [...new Set(mapedTopicsArray.flat())];
console.log(topicsArrayMergedWithoutDuplicates );
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const mapedTopicsArray = [
                            ['javascript', 'reactjs'],
                            ['Java', 'reactjs'],                   
                         ]


const result = mapedTopicsArray
    .reduce((acc, prev) => acc.concat(prev), [])
    .filter(ifThisItemFirstAppearance)

function ifThisItemFirstAppearance(value, index, self) {
    return self.indexOf(value) === index
}

console.log(result)
```

First reduce the list of lists into a list, then filter repeated items.

*Partial credit to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/get-all-unique-values-in-a-javascript-array-remove-duplicates) on how to filter duplicates*